# SSO with services talking to each other

Tags: authentication, authorization, single-sign-on

What we want: An Auth Service has/manages users and their permissions. The users don't know about this service, they only see the User Facing Application. The latter needs to get data from a Resource Service which checks with the Auth Service which data may be delivered. Something like this:

```
      +------------+
      | User Agent |
      +------------+
            |
+-----------v-------------+
| User Facing Application |
+-------------------------+
            |
   +--------v---------+         +--------------+
   | Resource Service +---------> Auth Service |
   +------------------+         +--------------+
```

Probably there are some arrows missing here in order for this to work. I understand that in order to authorize a service to access another service on behalf of a user I need to use OAuth or similar. However, the users should not be aware that there are separate services. Same problem with SSO solutions IINM.

We control the Resource Service and the Auth Service, we don't control the User Facing Application (meaning, it's not trustworthy).

What technology (if there is any) allows me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In one of my projects, the session tokens are managed by the central auth service. By doing so, all the requests from the frontend to the backend comes with the session token, by cookies for instance. The backend can then validate the session with the auth service and decide the permissions of the user based on the authorization rules. Basically it looks like:

```
      +------------+
      | User Agent |
      +------------+
            | session
+-----------v-------------+
| User Facing Application |
+-------------------------+
            | session
   +--------v---------+ validate +--------------+
   | Resource Service +----------> Auth Service |
   +------------------+          +--------------+
```

The session should be created when the user is authenticated. In my solution, the frontend displays the login UI and sends authentication requests to the auth service. A session is returned to the frontend on success. Then the above data flow is used to authorize every request afterwards.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what server side rending has to do with SSO. I'm not talking about SEO, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: Ah sorry, indeed I misread your question. As for SSO I have only few experiences but it may help in some aspects.